# How to configure Docker in windows to listen to tcp?

Tags: tcp, docker

I'v tried to connect to the Docker remote API directly from http but without succes. I just can't figure out where to go from now.

export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.**.**:2376"

didn't work.

The docker i am using is the latest Docker toolbox for windows environmnent.
This comes with the preconfigured Docker CLI shell which by default only listens for unix socker connections. Can anyone tell me how to configure the docker daemon to listen to tcp so i can make httpcalls from my java environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this as follows; I have set TLS_VERIFY environment variable in the dockerhost to no. By that doing the remote api is open and listening on 2376

Answer (score -2):

To connect your docker client to a remote machine you should use the `env` command of `docker-machine` (see: [docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/)).

Depending on the shell you are using (CMD, Powershell or Bash), you must specify your shell type when you execute the command:

**Windows CMD**

```
docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd <name of your machine>
```

Copy the output and run it in your cmd session.

**Windows PowerShell**

```
docker-machine.exe env --shell powershell <name of your machine> | Invoke-Expression
```

**Docker CLI / Bash**

```
eval $(docker-machine.exe env <name of your machine>)
```